# Elementary set theory and the reuse of previously defined notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a text with deals with a type of objects $x$, I define a set like 
$\mathcal{S}=\{x\in\mathcal{K}\mid p(x)\}$. Someone I know claims this is wrong because $\mathcal{S}$ will 'inherit' properties that are defined for $x$ elsewhere in my text. In particular, it may very well be the case that $x\notin\mathcal{K}$. The right way, they argue, is to write $\mathcal{S}=\{y\in\mathcal{K}\mid p(y)\}$ instead. But I believe that, by definition, the $\{\cdot|$ part of a set $\{\cdot \mid \cdot\}$ cannot depend on anything aside from $\mathcal{K}$ and the ${}\mid\cdot\}$ part. The ${}\mid\cdot\}$ part may however depend on objects defined elsewhere. Am I wrong? Can you provide me with a textbook for reference?

Comment: $\{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}$ and $\{y\in\mathcal{K}:p(y)\}$ are absolutely synonymous: $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables. if you have previously defined $x$, you should not use it as a dummy variable in defining $\mathcal{S}$, but the same goes equally for $y$.

Comment: That was quick, thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: If "someone you know" still doesn't get it, consider  a loop in a computer program , in which  a variable symbol may be "local" to the loop.

Comment: what if there are two sets - is the $x$ mutual? in this case we need two variables

Comment: @JonMark: There is no need for two variables: the $x$ in $\{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}$ and the $x$ in $\{x\in\mathcal{L}:q(x)\}$ are completely unrelated. The expressions $$\{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}\cap\{x\in\mathcal{L}:q(x)\}$$ and $$\{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}\cap\{y\in\mathcal{L}:q(y)\}$$ are synonymous.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott; even if you use them at the same time?

Comment: @JonMark: Yes. It was precisely to make that point that I used them in a single expression in my example.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott; so if I call the top one A and the bottom one B, there's no confusion? is $A\cup B$ A or B?

Comment: @JonMark: $$\{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}\cap\{x\in\mathcal{L}:q(x)\} = \{x\in\mathcal{K}:p(x)\}\cap\{y\in\mathcal{L}:q(y)\}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46150/discussion-between-jonmark-perry-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Formally**, the $x$ in $\{x\in K\mid p(x)\}$ is *bound by* the set builder notation, so it is "not visible" from outside the set builder and is completely distinct from any uses the letter $x$ may have outside it.

So for example,
$$ \bigl\{x\in\mathbb R \bigm| x-1 \in \{ x\in \mathbb R \mid x+x=x \} \bigr\} $$
is exactly the same as
$$ \bigl\{x\in\mathbb R \bigm| x-1 \in \{ y\in \mathbb R \mid y+y=y \} \bigr\} = \{ x\in\mathbb R \mid x-1 \in \{0\} \} = \{1\} $$
and cannot have any other meaning than this.

---

However **in practice** using a dummy variable to "shadow" another use of the same variable letter can be **confusing** for a human reader and invites mistakes when he tries to disentagle what you have written. Since the purpose of mathematical writing is to *communicate ideas to other humans*, rather than instructing a machine, you **should not do this** without having a good reason to. And even if you have a good reason, you should probably also call out the potential for confusion explicitly in the surrounding text.

Comment: Do you know how to formalize such a variable-binding mechanism?

Comment: @Eric.  This is a topic covered in the theory of formal mathematical or logical languages, and in  Model Theory.

Comment: @Eric: Yes. It is rare to see the gritty details of it written out in the context of _mathematics_, though -- because the mathematicians who care about such formalization usually prefer to work with a smaller formal language for technical convenience and view set builders as merely (semi-formal) abbreviations. Any halfway good text in _mathematical logic_ should show you how it works for _quantifiers_, and texts about the _lambda calculus_ typically go on at length about shadowing and capture problems. (...)

Comment: (...) For the general case of other kinds of binders, one's best bet might be to go for a computer-science text in _programming language semantics_, where having to juggle different kinds of binders is a standard occurrence.

Comment: @Eric: Note that some programming languages forbid **variable shadowing**, which is the technical term given to such variable binding semantics. Mainstream languages like C/C++/Java/Javascript allow it, but trust me that it causes a huge headache especially during debugging time. You will find that CS people are more familiar with such things simply because they need to get the computer to work, and computers don't know one **bit** of what they have in their head, and can only follow purely mechanical instructions. So any variable appearing in a computer program better have precise reference!

Comment: @user21820: Java does forbid shadowing between local variables (and formal parameters) within one method.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes but annoyingly not between local variables (or method parameters) and fields of the containing class. I personally never use shadowing as I always make mistakes no matter how careful I try to be! Also, Java allows methods to have the same name even if the only difference in signature is that one uses a native data type and another uses a normal type. This caused me headache before when combined with generics and autoboxing, such as with say `remove(T item)` and `removeAt(int position)` when used with `T = Integer`.

Comment: Thank you all. By the way, I found the *Mathematica*'s Hold, HoldAll, HoldComplete, and so on "prevent variables from evaluating while passing it to the function arguments" mechanism are quite useful and unique. And I wonder that if it can be more or less turn to inspired the mathematics?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example:

> Be $x=3$. Be $M=\{x\in\mathbb N|x=5\}$.

Does $M$ contain any elements? Is it empty because $3\ne 5$, or does it contain the single element $5$? That depends on  whether the $x$ on the right hand side of the set builder notation refers to the $x$ defined on the left hand side, or to the $x$ defined before. In short, inside the definition of $M$,  you've got *two* conflicting definition of $x$: One that says that $x=3$, and one that says that $x$ is an arbitrary element of $\mathbb N$.

Therefore the simple rule is: Don't do it. If you have different entities, give them different names.

Note however, that the name *inside* the set builder notation is only defined inside that notation, so there's nothing wrong with reusing that in another set building, as for example:

> Be $A = \{x\in\mathbb N|x > 0\}$ and $B = \{x\in\mathbb N|x < 10\}$.

Also note that if the names are not already in use, it indeed does not matter which name you use, so $\{x\in X|P(x)\}$ and $\{y\in X|P(y)\}$ are indeed the same set.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Henning is technically correct that in your first example, the set-builder notation binds $x$, so that formally speaking we usually allow that and the set would be $\{5\}$, not empty. However, this is just something done for convenience in formal logic, and is not necessarily considered syntactically correct in common mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

If you've used $x$ before in a specific way, then using it again like this will confuse your reader, though it is not technically incorrect - the format $\{x \in K \mid p(x)\}$ carries the implication that $x$ is being treated as a new variable. But if you say, for example, "$x = 4; \{x \in K \mid p(x)\}$", it'll be all kinds of confusing - by $p(x)$, do you mean to say that $p$ holds of the variable $x \in K$, or the $x$ which is $4$?

Unless it's this specific, I wouldn't worry about it - for example,"$\{x \in K \mid p(x)\}, \{x \in K \mid q(x)\}$" is fine. Likewise, if you defined $x$ to be $4$, but it was two pages earlier and you aren't going to use it again, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very similar to asking what is the difference between:

$$x^2+3x+2=0$$
$$y^2+3y+2=0$$

And the answer is, **absolutely nothing!**.

Comment: If you previously declared  that $x\ge 42$, then there indeed is a difference between both equations, as the first one then has no solution, while the second one has two solutions.

Comment: This may not be a proper example. The set notation really have a variable binding, and the "equations" are definitely not.